# Value outside of valid range when trying to save latitude/longitude on Geolocation field

Tags: apex, geolocation

This is the error I'm getting.

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE, DC_geocode: value outside of valid range on numeric field: -117.3411: [DC_geocode__c]

The background on this is that I'm passing in two Decimal values(by necessity) to a method, then I try to set the latitude and longitude of a custom Geolocation field by using those two Decimal values and converting them to double values by doing the following.

DC_geocode__latitude__s = decimalvalue1.doubleValue();
DC_geocode__longitude__s = decimalvalue2.doubleValue();

I've set my custom Geolocation field to use these types of values(instead of degrees and minutes) with a precision of 15 decimal places.

Any help you could give me on trying to figure out why this error may be occurring in this instance would be great!

Comment: Can you write out the values of `decimalvalue1.doubleValue()` and  `decimalvalue2.doubleValue()` to the debug log to check what values you are trying to set.

Comment: @MarkKeats here is the debug 

07:58:46.984 (14984211718)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[23]|latitude|Decimal|false|false
07:58:46.984 (14984220731)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[23]|latitude|-117.3411
07:58:46.984 (14984225253)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[23]|longitude|Decimal|false|false
07:58:46.984 (14984231246)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[23]|longitude|38.1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have your latitude and longitude the wrong way around.

> - Latitudes range from -90 to 90
> - Longitudes range from -180 to 180

Your latitude is -117, so outside the valid range.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Guess I need to take a break!